# What's the purpose of the Maven 3 ciManagement configuration?

Tags: maven-3

I've read the section [in the Maven documentation](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Continuous_Integration_Management), but I haven't really seen any evidence of plugins using the `<ciManagement>` tag in a project POM.

My question is:

- Are there CI systems that will use this information in some intelligent way?
- Other than project self-documentation, is there any other benefit to specifying and maintaining this information in my project POM?
- Does Maven itself (or any common plugins) use this information?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

for documentation sample http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/integration.html

Historically this element was used by continuum for more details see http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.4/maven-model/maven.html#class_ciManagement it was possible to define the pom notifiers (mail,irc) and where to send notification.

Comment: Thank you Olivier! Besides Continuum, are you aware of any other CI systems (or plugins) which use this information? I noted an open Jenkins JIRA (JENKINS-1201) suggesting that support for this would be helpful, but it seems not to have ever been fixed.

Comment: If you use Sonar, it will use that information to add a link inside Sonar to your CI job page.

Answer (score 5):

[SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/) uses the `<ciManagement>` element of the pom to define the value of its own `sonar.links.ci` configuration property. This property is mentioned in the [SonarQube documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Project+Administration), but there's no explanation about what is it used for. It turns out it's one more thing to keep up-to-date. I would try to remove it from the pom to see if any visible issue comes up.

Answer (score 5):

You can look [here](https://github.com/apache/maven-plugins/blob/a9566e14f980ff52f3ee3c89d64d6b98b03c0305/maven-project-info-reports-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/report/projectinfo/CiManagementReport.java#L129-L170) to find data about what types of `<ciManagement/>` are valid.

There's probably a better way than pointing to that hash, but the way the `maven-plugins` repo works is odd.